# Run mail-listener on loading page in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor

While creating an app for listening inbound emails in Meteor, I found a problem with starting the listener. In my project I base on [simple-todos](https://github.com/meteor/simple-todos) example. Everything works fine, I have insertion for Mongo DB, but I can't start the listener.

Code of the listener (based on [mail-listener2](https://atmospherejs.com/cscottnet/mail-listener2) - uses node-imap and mailparser):

```
    var MailListener = require('mail-listener2'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    jsonfile = require('jsonfile'),
    config;

config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.cwd()+"/config.json","utf-8"));

var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: config.username,
  password: config.password,
  host: config.imap.host,
  port: config.imap.port,
  tls: config.imap.secure,
  tlsOptions: config.imap.rejectUnauthorized,
  mailbox: config.imap.mailbox,
  fetchUnreadOnStart: config.imap.fetchUnreadOnStart,
  mailParserOptions: config.imap.stream,
  attachments: config.imap.download, 

mailListener.start(); // start listening

mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
  console.log("imapConnected");
});

mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
  console.log("imapDisconnected");
});

mailListener.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

mailListener.on("mail", function(mail){
  var tresc = mail.text,
      regexp = new RegExp(/\d+/),
      token = regexp.exec(tresc);

  var date = mail.date.toString('utf8');
  var obj = {"token" : token, "startTime" : date};
  jsonfile.writeFile("token.json",obj, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});
```

In my Meteor app I am trying to put this code in `Template.body.events` to start it with app start. App is working, I can add items to Mongo manually and Meteor reacts, but not with listener. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Why is this tied to the Template, and more importantly why try to tie into the event on the template?  If you need to tie it to the template, it seems like either onRendedered or onCreated might be a better choice.  But, if you want to the mail listener running all the time, it would be better to configure and start it in a more common area.

Comment: It was tied to the template, becuase I thought that it is the only was to use event in that area. Where can I start the listener to have access to object returned by the listener (I mean the email)?

Comment: Are you using ES6 yet?  Typically, you would put code like that in the server folder, in a separate .JS file.  With ES6, you would need to export the variable you need.  Most people using ES6 create a function to init their server-side stuff, then simply call it from index.js somewhere.  If you are not using ES6, then just put a *.js file somewhere and Meteor should read it and run whatever is in it.  I would still suggest creating an init function then calling said function.

Comment: According to Meteor documentation and my onw knowledge, I put the part of the code responsible for start of the listener in the `server/main.js` and I put a log to to throw if is connected. It works now, but I am still working on, how to made the app react on "mail" event? This event is specified in one of the npm packeges, I don't know how to get access to it in meteor.

Comment: Seems like you would want to listen for the relavent even in the server code somewhere, and either update something in Mongo to push updates to the client, or setup something manually to push and/or pull data to the client.  You could write a custom "publication" that does this without a backing collection.  But, this is getting more into best architecture, and not really related to the original problem.  Glad you figured it out, though.