# Javascript event for incoming mail in 'mail-listener2'

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

My previous [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588953/run-mail-listener-on-loading-page-in-meteor) was about running Meteor mail-listener2. Now that I know how to do it, I am wondering, how to make Meteor react to an event 'mail' defined in 'mail-listener2'. The listener is worthless without reacting to this event.

Free running JavaScript file of the whole process is in mentioned above post.

Answer (score 0):

The "magic" that allows Meteor to be reactive between the client and server is DDP, and you can leverage it a few ways.

One way would be to have your listener simply write something to the MongoDB and have the normal flow of Pub/Sub handle it.  Basically, you create a collection that represents your messages.  The server publishes and the client subscribes to said collection.  Finally, your "mail" listener code would simply create a document, place it in the collection, and the rest should be handled by the normal flow.

An alternative would be to hack together your own DDP update publication.  Without going too much into it, you can actually create a Pub/Sub stream that isn't actually backed by a collection at all.  I gave a talk on this at the Tampa Meteor's Meetup last July, and the examples I gave can be found [here](https://github.com/mbabauer/meteor_publicationsDemo).  In particular, if you check out the code in [pubSubDemo2](https://github.com/mbabauer/meteor_publicationsDemo/tree/master/pubSubDemo2) you will see where I create several such publications, one of which uses the `fs` module from Node to monitor the filesystem status and push it up to the client.  On the client-side it uses minimongo like usual, so the code there works the same way you are used to.

Comment: I understand everything, I have implement publications and subscriptions and this is working fine. The only problem is I can start the listener, but the listener in his codes emits an event called "mail". Listener react on this event every time, when new message arrives. In my first solution I assumed, that I have to put reaction on this event in `Template.body.listener`, so the listener could react in any moment. The "mail" event is not a common event, it is implement only for the npm 'mail-listener2' module :(

Comment: That's not how Meteor reactivity works.  There are two parts that have to be implemented.  The first part is `Tracker.autorun()`, which runs a function, then re-runs whenever it's dependency change.  The second is actual dependency, which you create using `Tracker.Dependency`.  This is what triggers the `autorun()` that a dependency has changed.  The Template methods all implement the `autorun()` part, which is where the reactivity happens in the helpers and lifecycle methods.  What you are missing is the other side, and since it's not a Meteor package, I doubt its reactive OOTB.

Comment: It would be possible to implement Tracker to make this reactive.  What I would suggest would be to wrap the mail event listener, listen for the `mail` event, then update your `Tracker.Dependency` to trigger reactivity.  But, it would be just as easy to simply pump something into a collection and let Meteor handle it.